# STM32H723 HSE frequency for usb + ethernet at 550MHz

Tags: stm32h7

Is there a HSE frequency that will provide the desired target frequencies for a 550MHz cpu clock, usb, and ethernet?

Using STM32CubeIDE I've plugged in an 8MHz HSE and 550MHz cpu core but this is showing a 110MHz click into USB. Shouldn't this be 48MHz?

The nucleo stm32h745 board (lower processor speed) has its HSE at 8MHz from the stm-link processor, so 8MHz seems like a good shot but I don't trust the STM32CubeIDE values yet.

Can anyone confirm a HSE that fits these requirements?